# Golang TCP EOF when Receiving Messages NEARLY Concurrently

Tags: go, tcp

I have this Golang TCP server that listens to a device. The device should send a hello message, then the server responses with a hello back. After that, the device sends data. Once the data is sent, the devices sends a commit request to check if the data was received. The issue is, I'm not receiving the commit requests. It's almost like the data and commit request are sent at the same time as the logged time stamps are 0.1 seconds apart. However, I know I am receiving SOMETHING because after the data is sent, I get this in the logs:

```
Device IP: 13.56.127.98:65145, Timestamp: 2023-08-07T21:23:40.893412845Z 
        Error reading header: EOF
```

Here's the server code as well:

```
package servers

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func Server() {
    PORT := ":8081"
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", PORT)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer l.Close()
    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())

    for {
        c, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        // Set TCP keep-alive settings
        if tcpConn, ok := c.(*net.TCPConn); ok {
            // Enable TCP keep-alive
            tcpConn.SetKeepAlive(true)

            // Set the time period for sending TCP keep-alive probes
            keepAlivePeriod := 60 * time.Hour // Adjust this value as needed
            tcpConn.SetKeepAlivePeriod(keepAlivePeriod)
        }
        go func() {
            defer c.Close()
            handleConnection(c)
        }()
    }
}

func handleConnection(c net.Conn) {
    defer c.Close()

    data := make([]byte, 4096)

    for {
        //log device ip
        fmt.Printf("Device IP: %s, Timestamp: %s \n", c.RemoteAddr().String(), time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339Nano))
        // Read the communication header from the connection
        //_, err := c.Read(data)
        _, err := bufio.NewReader(c).Read(data)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("   Error reading header:", err)
            return
        }

        // Check the sync bytes
        if data[0] != 0x02 || data[1] != 0x55 {
            fmt.Println("   Invalid sync bytes")
            //log actual bytes received
            fmt.Printf("    Received: %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X\n", data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4])
            return
        }

        // Get the message type from the header
        messageType := data[2]

        // get payload length
        payloadLengthBytes := data[3:5]
        payloadLength := binary.LittleEndian.Uint16(payloadLengthBytes)

        // Handle the different message types
        switch messageType {
        case 0:
            fmt.Println("   Received Hello message:")
            sendHelloResponse(c)
        case 4:
            // Send data records
            fmt.Println("   Received Send data records message:")
        case 5:
            // Commit request
            fmt.Println("   Received Commit request message:")
        // ... more cases follow
        }
    }
}
```

I'm assuming it's some issue with the for loop and reading the data. The buffer size should be more than large enough too as each message is maybe 500 bytes total.

Comment: One, very minor, problem is you `defer c.Close()` twice. More important is you seem to have a misunderstanding how TCP works. It is a streaming protocol and messages can be split at arbitrary boundaries and sent in separate packets. Just because the sender wrote "hello" does not mean your `bufio.NewReader(c).Read(data)` is going to return the entire message. Beyond that as Charlie pointed out a bufio.Reader buffers data it receives and you may be throwing away data received but not read by your server.

Comment: @CharlieTumahai I would have to include the bufio.Reader in the for loop in order to continuously read messages from the client. If not included in the for loop, wouldn't it just read the initial message?

Comment: @KurtisRader I'm fully aware of how TCP works. In what sense would bufio.NewReader(c).Read(data) not return "hello" (the entire message in this case) if the client wrote "hello"? That's the entire purpose of the function - to return the message wrote by the client. There are certain cases that this would be possible (buffer size, connection timeout, etc), but I accounted for all these. Also, in what way would I be throwing away data received. It appears you're being entirely negative and pointing out arbitrary problems without offering a solution or any helpful information.

Comment: @LUKER, To expand on my previous comment your misconception is that client send message boundaries are guaranteed to be retained when the data reaches the server. **That is incorrect.** It is only true for protocols such as UDP.

Comment: @user207421: I wrote no such thing. You are quoting the person who opened this question. That person is the one who believes that TCP preserves message boundaries as defined by the writes performed by the sender. Please take a little more time to read and comprehend what has been written and who wrote it. Especially in light of the fact that by the time you commented I had made two more comments directed at the O.P. which echoed your point. I recognize you probably meant to direct your comment to the O.P. but wish there was a way to downvote comments. :-)

Comment: @LUKER: Your understanding about how TCP works is almost always true when the client and server are on the same local area network. Which, if that is the extent of your experience, explains why you have that misconception. But even on a LAN your mental model of how TCP works will occasionally be violated resulting in unexpected errors. TCP is a streaming protocol that does not guarantee individual writes by a client can be read in their entirety by a server issuing a single read.

Comment: @LUKER  'That's the entire purpose of the function - to return the message wrote by the client.' No it isn't. There is no such thing as a message in TCP, as everybody has been telling you.

Comment: @KurtisRader Oops my bad, fixed that.

Comment: @KurtisRader I apologize if informing you of these things made you upset. It seems you have a pretty closed mind when it comes to this issue and my understanding of this issue. I and others would appreciate it in the future if you were less condescending and ignorant in your comments though! While you didn't propose an answer or anything helpful at all, I appreciate the attention you brought to this post. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In this answer, I apply the good suggestions from the question comments. Set NOTEs describing the changes.

```
func Server() {
    PORT := ":8081"
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", PORT)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer l.Close()
    // rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix()) NOTE: not needed in GO 1.20 or later.

    for {
        c, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        // Set TCP keep-alive settings
        if tcpConn, ok := c.(*net.TCPConn); ok {
            // Enable TCP keep-alive
            tcpConn.SetKeepAlive(true)

            // Set the time period for sending TCP keep-alive probes
            keepAlivePeriod := 60 * time.Hour // Adjust this value as needed
            tcpConn.SetKeepAlivePeriod(keepAlivePeriod)
        }
        // NOTE: anonymous function eliminated here by
        // eliminating extra call to defer c.Close()
        go handleConnection(c)
    }
}

func handleConnection(c net.Conn) {
    defer c.Close()
    data := make([]byte, 4096)

    // NOTE: create buffer once and reuse.
    br := bufio.NewReader(c)

    for {
        // NOTE: use io.ReadFull to read complete header.
        _, err := io.ReadFull(br, data[:5])
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("   Error reading header:", err)
            return
        }

        // Check the sync bytes
        if data[0] != 0x02 || data[1] != 0x55 {
            fmt.Println("   Invalid sync bytes")
            //log actual bytes received
            fmt.Printf("    Received: %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X\n", data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4])
            return
        }

        // Get the message type from the header
        messageType := data[2]

        // Get payload
        // NOTE: Use io.ReadFUll again.
        payloadLength := binary.LittleEndian.Uint16(data[3:5])
        _, err = io.ReadFull(br, data[:payloadLength])
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("   Error reading payload:", err)
            return
        }

        // Handle the different message types
        switch messageType {
        case 0:
            fmt.Println("   Received Hello message:")
            //sendHelloResponse(c)
        case 4:
            // Send data records
            fmt.Println("   Received Send data records message:")
        case 5:
            // Commit request
            fmt.Println("   Received Commit request message:")
            // ... more cases follow
        }
    }
}
```

[Run the code on the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/mGJGOI4Abg0).

Comment: You're still making assumptions that the buffer is full, or at least that it contains both the type and the entire length word.

Comment: @user207421 The code in this answer assumes that io.ReadFull fills the slice or returns an error if fewer bytes were read. Are you saying that io.ReadFull does not do that?

Comment: @mandifroit: A casual glance at your solution suggests it is the correct solution. I'm simply too tired and annoyed by the O.P. to spend more time evaluating your answer given the O.P.'s antagonism to feedback.

Comment: @user207421 Here's the code in the answer with  [iotest,OneByteReader](https://pkg.go.dev/testing/iotest#OneByteReader) plumbed in to show that I am not making the assumption that you claim: https://go.dev/play/p/aMrBnnMYOFc